# Como fazer um upload no Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

> Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Denuncia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AlunoController extends Controller
{
 public function alunoInsert(Request $request)
{
    //é bom fazer as verificações antes
    
    $extension = $request->uploaded_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    //gera um numero unico baseado no timestamp atual
    $name = uniqid();
    //salva um nome baseado no id
    $nameFile = "{$name}.{$extension}";
    // Faz o upload:
    $upload = $request->uploaded_file->storeAs('denuncias', $nameFile);
    //envia o nome do arquivo de uma vez
    $denuncia = Denuncia::create([
        'id_usuario' => 63,
        'imagem' => $nameFile,
        ]);
        
        
        return response()->json($request);
    }

}
```

> Está dando esse erro
>
> {message: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on
> null",…} exception:
> "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError" file:
> "/var/www/html/nsi/app/Http/Controllers/AlunoController.php" line: 23
> message: "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on
> null" trace: [{function: "alunoInsert", class:
> "App\Http\Controllers\AlunoController", type: "->"},…]

- 

> **Linha 23** $extension = $request->uploaded_file->getClientOriginalExtension();

- 

> **SOLUÇÃO DA PERGUNTA**

```
public function alunoInsert(Request $request)
    {
      
        
        if($request->hasFile('uploaded_file')){
            $image = $request->file('uploaded_file');
            $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/img_denuncia');

            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);


            $denuncia = Denuncia::create([
                'imagem' => $name
            ]);
    
        }

        return response()->json($request);
    }
```

Comment: Seu input esta com name `uploaded_file`?

Comment: Sim, já revisei tudo, não sei porque está dando erro.

Comment: Percebi um erro e não sei se é isso, mas no action do formulário você está mandando para uma rota diferente da que você tá recuperando os dados.
`action="{{ route('rotaListarAluno') }}"`
Troque para:
`action="{{ route('rotaInsertAluno') }}"`

Comment: Tente também verificar se está enviando o arquivo por meio da verificação `$request->hasFile('image')
` passando no lugar de image o nome do campo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um jeito simples também e..

```
if($request->hasFile('img')){
```

Verifica se o file existe

```
            $image = $request->file('img');
```

Armazena o file na variável imagem

```
            $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Pega o nome com o time atual e concatena ao extensão do arquivo

```
            $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
```

Pega o destino do path aqui uso como exemplo pasta imagens dentro do public e use a função move para move-la para lá ai salva o nome do arquivo ou o caminho fica a escolha.

```
            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);

            $galery->img = $name;
            $galery->save();
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado DEU CERTO AQUI <3

Answer (score 8):

Vamos lá, o que eu vou explicar aqui você pode encontrar no [especializati](https://blog.especializati.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-no-laravel-com-request/).
Primeiramente, você tem que definir onde você quer salvar seus arquivos, podem ser na nuvem, localmente. Você define isso através dos discos em `/config/filesystems.php` na seguinte linha:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
```

No lugar de local você define o disco que quer utilizar.

Caso você escolha localmente, você tem que verificar se esse upload será usado em alguma `view` pelo usuário. E por que isso? Pois tudo que o usuário enxerga na aplicação é o que está dentro do diretório `public`.
Para resolver isso você deve modificar de local para public na seguinte linha:

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),
```

E depois disso rodar o comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Que cria meio que um atalho ou link direto entre a pasta `public` e a pasta `storage`. Uma dica é se estiver usando o Windows pra rodar o comando, certifique-se de rodar o terminal em modo administrador.
Feito isso, na sua tag `form` você deverá colocar o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`que faz com que se reconheça os arquivos na requisição:

```html
<form action="url-aqui" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    ...
</form>
```

Você pode recuperar então seu arquivo no controlador da seguinte maneira:

```
$arquivo = $request->file('image');
```

ou

```
$arquivo = $request->image;
```

Além disso você pode fazer verificações, se é um arquivo válido por exemplo. Ou também recuperar o nome do arquivo, a extensão, o mime type, etc.
Verificações:

```
// Se informou o arquivo, retorna um boolean
$file = $request->hasFile('image')

// Se é válido, retorna um boolean
$file = $request->file('image')->isValid()
```

Recuperando informações:

```
// Retorna mime type do arquivo (Exemplo image/png)
$request->imagem->getMimeType()

// Retorna o nome original do arquivo
$request->imagem->getClientOriginalName() 

// Extensão do arquivo
$request->imagem->getClientOriginalExtension()
$request->imagem->extension()

// Tamanho do arquivo
$request->imagem->getClientSize()
```

Ai para fazer o upload em si você pode utilizar a função `store` do `Request`, que salva o arquivo do jeito que está ou `storeAs`, que você indica o nome do arquivo, o primeiro argumento é o nome da pasta em que sera salvo, no caso ele salva no disco default, mas da para passar o disco também:

```
$upload = $request->image->store('products');
$upload = $request->image->storeAs('products', 'novonome.jpg');
```

Vou dar duas soluções, pelo fato de que é interessante salvar um nome único para o arquivo para evitar problemas:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Denuncia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AlunoController extends Controller
{
    public function alunoInsert(Request $request)
    {
        //é bom fazer as verificações antes

        $extension = $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
     //salva normal a denuncia e depois que salvar o arquivo, altera o nome no banco
        $denuncia = Denuncia::create([
            'descricao' => $request->form,
            'qual_descricao' => $request->oque,
            'id_bloco' => $request->bloco,
            'id_denuncia_oque' => $request->local,
            'id_usuario' => 63,
            'imagem' => 'padrao.jpeg',
        ]);

    //salva um nome baseado no id
    $nameFile = "{$denuncia->id}.{$extension}";
    // Faz o upload:
    $upload = $request->image->storeAs('denuncias', $nameFile);
    //atualiza o nome da imagem no bd    
    $denuncia->imagem = $nameFile;
    $denuncia->save();

        return response()->json($request);
    }
}
```

ou:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Denuncia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class AlunoController extends Controller
{
    public function alunoInsert(Request $request)
    {
        //é bom fazer as verificações antes

        $extension = $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //gera um numero unico baseado no timestamp atual
        $name = uniqid();
        //salva um nome baseado no id
        $nameFile = "{$name}.{$extension}";
        // Faz o upload:
        $upload = $request->image->storeAs('denuncias', $nameFile);
        //envia o nome do arquivo de uma vez
        $denuncia = Denuncia::create([
            'descricao' => $request->form,
            'qual_descricao' => $request->oque,
            'id_bloco' => $request->bloco,
            'id_denuncia_oque' => $request->local,
            'id_usuario' => 63,
            'imagem' => $nameFile,
        ]);


        return response()->json($request);
    }
}
```

Para recuperar o arquivo na view você pode usar o helper asset e passar o caminho da imagem, conforme consta na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk):

```
<img src={{asset('storage/denuncias/'. $denuncia->imagem)}}>
```

Acho que é isso caso tenha alguma dúvida consulte a documentação. Lembrando que os exemplos dados aqui foram retirados da [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk) e do [especializati](https://blog.especializati.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-no-laravel-com-request/).

Comment: Bom fiz o passo a passo mas está dando erro, editei la poderia da uma olhada?

Answer (score 4):

Conforme a documentação (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#file-uploads), você só precisa utilizar a função file do request:

`$path = $request->file('imagem')->storeAs('pasta_das_imagens', 'nome_da_imagem.jpg');`

Despois basta salvar o path ou o nome escolhido ao invés do nome fixo:

```
$denuncia = Denuncia::create([
    ...
    'imagem' => $path,
]);
```