# Laravel - Foreach Mostrar imagem

Tags: laravel, imagem, foreach

Necessito de uma pequena ajuda relativamente a mostrar imagem num foreach.
Atualmente guardo o caminho para a imagem na store/app/utilizador.

Na view quando faço o foreach, mostra-me a "C:\xampp\tmp\php1CB9.tmp"

```
 @foreach($itens as $item)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$item->foto}}</td>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente você está com alguns problemas aí.

Primeiro se está salvando "C:\xampp\tmp\php1CB9.tmp", então o teu processo para salvar a imagem pode estar com problema.
Pode começar verificando na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem).
E [aqui também pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/363771/como-fazer-um-upload-no-laravel-5-7).

Segundo:
Dependendo de como você está salvando essa imagem você vai conseguir exibir ela com uma tag  e utilizando a função asset(). [Pode ver na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset)
Exemplo:

```
<img src="{{ asset($item->foto) }}" />
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Já fiz a alteração e na BD já aparecem a imagem jpg. Não estou a conseguir visualizar a imagem. Terei de colocar o caminho total da imagem? 
storage/app/{{ asset($item->foto) }}

Comment: Para o padrão do Laravel você teria que colocar a imagem em storage/app/public/imagem.jpg. Para usar em outra pasta pode dar uma olhada sobre como tornar pública a storage/app, mais detalhes pode olhar [aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk). Se não quiser colocar as imagens dentro do padrão storage/app/public, tu pode ou modificar a configuração de links simbólicos ou adicionar um novo link simbólico no arquivo config/filesystem.php do Laravel e depois rodar o comando 'php artisan storage:link'.

Answer (score -3):

Você precisa primeiro salvar a foto em alguma pasta real, geralmente no Controller devido.

Mas indo direto ao ponto, dá pra usar `<img src="{{ asset("diretorio_da_foto/".$item->foto) }}">` dentro desse `<td>`.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).